# How To get keys(index) of collection in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, chart.js

I am using laravel and I have one collection and there are some collection in it so I want to get index of each collection

my collection is like this

```
 Collection {#4415 ▼
  #items: array:14 [▼
    "01" => Collection {#4311 ▶}
    "02" => Collection {#4318 ▶}
    "07" => Collection {#4325 ▶}
    10 => Collection {#4338 ▶}
    12 => Collection {#4345 ▶}
    13 => Collection {#4352 ▶}
    14 => Collection {#4359 ▶}
    18 => Collection {#4366 ▶}
    20 => Collection {#4373 ▶}
    21 => Collection {#4380 ▶}
    25 => Collection {#4387 ▶}
    26 => Collection {#4400 ▶}
    27 => Collection {#4407 ▶}
    31 => Collection {#4414 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I want to get for example 01 02 03 04 05 they are days of the month and I want to use them for chart js

Comment: Tried this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keys ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter collection helper.

```
$result = $yourCollection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return in_array($key, ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05']);
});
```

Or externally if you want to pass that array,

```
$monthArr =   ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05'];
$result = $yourCollection->filter(function ($value, $key) use($monthArr) 
{
    return in_array($key, $monthArr);
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get only keys of collection then,

```
$keys = $yourCollection->keys();
dd($keys);
```

Here is link of [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-keys).

Comment: it just get two collection I want all index of collection 01 to 31 for that example

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get only the keys of the collections you can use [keys method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-keys)

Comment: thanks a lot it works for me :) $nativeContentViewDays->keys()